# How do I properly use z-index?

Tags: html, css

I have a small problem, there is a div inside, there is a design like in the picture, I want the overflowing sides not to be seen when the heart in the design overflows from the left side, how can I do this?

[image]

```html
<IconKalp class="absolute left-[-20px] top-5 w-[108px] h-[90px]" style="z-index: 1;" />
<IconKalp class="absolute right-0 bottom-10 z-10 w-[250px]" />
```

Comment: Please format your question so we can read it properly

Comment: If you want to discuss an HTML and CSS problem, then you should show some actual HTML and CSS. Not sure what `IconKalp` is supposed to be, but native HTML it sure ain't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the parent Div or element that makes your container design, make that div like so

```
overflow: hidden;
```